# getInitialUrl is not working when the app is in background using deeplinking in android

Tags: react-native

When the app is in background i would like to navigate to the into app 
from the chrome  or message through link but it is navigating when i have removed the instance

```
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
        this.navigate(url);
      });
    } else {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
    //  AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    //  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  navigate = url => {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    var routeName;
    if (url != null) {
      console.log('Url not null:' + url);
      const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');
      const id = route.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
      routeName = route.split('/')[1];
    }

    if (routeName != null && routeName === 'B') {
      ///  alert('routeName: ' + routeName);
      navigate('People');
    }
  };
```

When i press the link it should navigate to the app if even the app is in background

Answer (score 1):

Applying these method while app is in background works in my case

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
_handleOpenURL(event) {
  console.log(event.url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with hooks, that will enable you to always have the url that opened the app from closed or background state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getUrlAsync = async () => {
        const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
        console.log(initialUrl);
    };
    getUrlAsync();

    const handleOpenURL = (event) => { console.log(event.url); };
    Linking.addEventListener("url", handleOpenURL);
    return () => Linking.removeEventListener("url", handleOpenURL);
}, []);
```